# Assigning null value using assignment operator is not working. -Uima Ruta

Tags: operators, uima, ruta

I tried to Assign a null value for a String using arithmetic operator but It's not working. It's assigning the previous value.

**Sample Input:**

```
Hi, How are you?  1
I'm Fine          2
```

**Sample Script:**

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;

DECLARE Page(STRING Id);
DECLARE PageId;
"Hi, How are you\\?  1"->Page;
"I'm Fine          2"->Page;
"1"{->PageId};

    BLOCK(foreach)Page{}
      {                      
        STRING pageid="null";
        PageId{->MATCHEDTEXT(pageid),LOG("PageId"+pageid)};
        Page{->Page.Id=pageid};
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's worked when I used

**STRING pageid;**

**ASSIGN(pageid,"null");**

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;

DECLARE Page(STRING Id);
DECLARE PageId;
"Hi, How are you\\?  1"->Page;
"I'm Fine          2"->Page;
"1"{->PageId};

    BLOCK(foreach)Page{}
      {        

        STRING pageid;
        ASSIGN(pageid,"null");
        PageId{->MATCHEDTEXT(pageid),LOG("PageId"+pageid)};
        Page{->Page.Id=pageid};
      }
```

Comment: But Still I have a doubt why it's not working when I used STRING pageid="null";